# Вёрстка: Swipe + RecyclerView(HORIZONTAL) + TextView

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Оранжевый - элементы recyclerView.
Синий - recyclerView.
Зелёный - TextVeiw.
Прямоугольник - область отображаемая пользователю.

Есть `recyclerView` с элементами. Под ним нужно разместить много `TextView`. Проблема в том, что если привязать снизу под `recyclerView`, то отображается TextView в самом низу экрана или вообще не отображается, ориентация `recyclerView` установлена `HORIZONTAL`.
Мне нужно получить отображение как на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`Activity`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRVPicturesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDescription"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swpLMA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDescription"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLMA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vEfnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvDescription"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvDescription"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`element`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLMA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_eye"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: используйте ConstraintLayout) он позволит сверстать адаптивный экран

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев и так на ConstraintLayout. Изображение на половину rv, а другая половина пустая.

Comment: а вы не могли бы привести весь код xml-ки?

Comment: если это ведь код, то TextView находиться вне родительского элемента (!!)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев привел не очень корректный вариант, который решает проблему, но грубо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использование `ConstraintLayout` (Для удобства).
2. Установить у значения высоты `0dp`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSomeList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```